# Agregação com MongoDB e $lookup

Tags: mongodb

Bom dia, estou tentando buscar dados de duas coleções diferentes com valores em comum usando o aggregate e o lookup, porém ao executar a consulta ela retorna vazia.
Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
db.createCollection("servidoropc")
db.servidoropc.insert({
"nome": "Servidor de ilha de testes 123",
"url": "OPCLabs.KitServer.2",
"ativo": true
});


db.grupocoletores.insert({
"nome": "Grupo de leitura ilha da foca",
"ativo": true,
"intervaloread": 5000,
"serveropcid": "5cd9ce0c5e5cbddb70dc3c61"
})

db.grupocoletores.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "servidoropc",
        localField: "serveropcid",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "server_opc"
     }
 }
```

])

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Ainda esta com problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta Certo porem vc esta salvando o "serveropcid" como uma string e nao como ObjectId.  Se tiver utilizando mongoosejs defina no schema.

Veja:[Lookup com pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Seu object da collection grupocoletores deve ficar assim:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d14c7cd3b15e7369d26f01c"),
"nome" : "Grupo de leitura ilha da foca",
"ativo" : true,
"intervaloread" : 5000,
"serveropcid" : ObjectId("5d14c7a23b15e7369d26f01b")
}
```